# How to insert/copy+paste unicode whitespace into a text file using editors like Textmate?

Tags: macos, unicode, editor, whitespace, textmate

I am trying to create a test csv file for a file cleaning script that is supposed to normalize all whitespace into "normal"/ "regular" whitespace character. The idea is I will insert a bunch of these oddball whitespace characters into this test file in some various locations.

Here are some sites that show these various and oddball whitespaces

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character
- http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html

I've tried to copy and paste from sources like that website but it seems like they always paste in as a normal space in Textmate. It could be that I am not copying what I think I am copying. In the past I've been able to copy and paste into Textmate special / unicode characters when I can clearly see what I am copying but with whitespace characters, I can't confirm since I can can't see it, so I am not sure if the problem is where I am copying from or that Textmate is converting it to the normal space when I paste it in.

If it is easier to use Textedit (the built in editor) or nano (command line editor) to do this I could use those. Or if there is another way other than copying and pasting that is better to get these into Textmate that would be an option.

I am on a MacbookPro running High Sierra MacOS.

Comment: Use [hexdump](http://charlespatricknewman.com/blog/mac-os-x-easy-way-to-do-a-hex-dump-of-a-file/) to dump out the file.  Then you'll know what's in it.  And nano won't help you but Textedit might.

Answer (score 0):

If you have LibreOffice installed you can use the spreadsheet application to create these using their hexidecimal equivalent in 1 cell then doing a conversion using

```
=unichar(hex2dec(cell_ref_to_1rst_cell)).
```

Far less confusing and you can save the spreadsheet complete with comments as a handy reference.   Then you should just be able to copy paste the cell with the unicode character when required.

[image]

Comment: I don't have LibreOffice installed. Can you confirm that this tool you are proposing I build for the purpose of generating a "source" of the whitespace characters, when copied and pasted from the cells of this tool into Textmate (or Textedit if you don't have Textmate) on a Mac will result in the actual space intended (i.e. those oddball spaces) vs a normal space? It seems like a long way to go to get to a copiable source but if I decided to try it, it would be good to know if the end part (the final result after pasting the copied source) actually works for you.

Comment: if you don't like that then you can follow this question on how to do it the MAC way....[https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/183045/how-can-i-type-unicode-characters-without-using-the-mouse]

Comment: Hmm, I didn't say I didn't like it to the degree I wouldn't explore it, I was just saying that the main issue here is that I need to confirm that its a solution for the issue which includes the copy/paste/insert process of ensuring I can end up with the specific whitespace in the text editor and there wasn't really any confirming that.  I've been able to copy visible unicode characters directly and I can confirm that the editor can receive visible unicode characters once copied. I am not sure if whitespace characters are handled differently in the paste or if it is with the source of the copy.

Comment: Looking at the other link you provided in the comment, it seems like there are a few answers that don't quite get to a usable solution for my challenge. The top answer refers to a "unicode hex decimal" that isn't like the hex decimal values shown in the wikipedia link on whitespace, it is some other type of value I am not sure how to convert to (outside of your formula in LibreOffice). The other one with the specific key mapping doesn't result in the same shortcut operation on my mac on high sierra. The last one may work but its missing a step I think for high sierra, will try that again later

Comment: LibreOffice is a free  and open-source suite of applications supported on Mac OS X 10.8 and higher. You can download it from [https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/?version=6.0.4&lang=en-US]

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using TextMate, various functions provided by the **Unicode bundle** could be helpful here (install via *Preferences → Bundles → Unicode*).

With this bundle installed you can use *Insert Unicode Character* <kbd>⌃⌥⌘I</kbd> to insert a character by name. Search for “space” to get a list of all space characters, then simply click on the desired character (the full title of a character is shown on hover):

[image: Insert Unicode Character]

Of course once inserted all the space characters look almost identical. To identify them, use *Show Unicode Name(s)* <kbd>⌃⌥⌘U 6</kbd>. This will display a tooltip showing the unicode of name of the character directly before the cursor (or the names of all selected characters, if a selection is active).

Also have a look at *Show Character Inventory* (press <kbd>⌃⌥⌘U</kbd> and then select the command from the popup menu): This provides a convenient overview of all the characters in your document (or in the selected text, if a selection is active).